# Visual studio 2015, Event is empty on property pane

Tags: events, visual-studio-2015, properties, mfc

I'm using visual studio 2015 & MFC. (windows 10)
Someday, Asynchronized resource & code.
When I check control or dialog's property, events list is empty.(message also)
I can't automatic create event handler function by clicking button.
Please, someone solve this problem.

All project same. Even I create new solution.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: I think it's not code level problem, because all projects have same problem even new project has that.

Comment: Please elaborate your question, maybe by getting help from someone who is fluent in English. As it stands here it is absolutely unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I think you are using the dialog editor and you are adding a button to the dialog. Visual Studio will automatically add matching source code to the *.cpp and header files. But sometimes that stops working. You can just add the code to source files manually.

Comment: Right. That's so terrible. I'd like to get solution

Comment: After updating visual studio 2015, It's cleared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because intellisense or its database is disable. I encountered this recently.
Check these options, should be:

IDE Tools menu -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Disable Database = False

IDE Tools menu -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Disable Intellisence = False

IDE Tools menu -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Rescan Solution Interval = 0

Open an empty VS IDE, fix the options, and reopen the project, everything should be fine.

@Michael Walz~ This guy illustrate this problem clearly enough, dont be nit-pick to  non-native speakers